# Multithreading regressions in Python

Tags: python, multithreading, parallel-processing, regression, python-multiprocessing

I have a project in Python that requires regressing many variables against many others. I am using a Jupyter Notebook for clarity but am also willing to use another IDE if it's easier. My code looks something like:

```
for a in dependent_variables:
    for b in independent_variables:
        regress a on b
```

My current dataset isn't huge, so this whole thing takes maybe 30 seconds, but I will soon have a much larger dataset that will significantly increase time required. I'm curious if this is a situation suitable for parallelization. Specifically, if I have a dual-threaded eight-core processor (meaning 16 CPUs total), is it possible to run simultaneous processes where each process regresses one of the first variables against one of the second variables, allowing me to complete, say, eight of these regressions at a time (if I allocate half of the CPUs to this process)? I am not super familiar with parallelization and most other answers I've found have discussed the parallelization of a single function call, not the simultaneous execution of multiple similar functions. I appreciate the help!

Comment: At first I have clear something up here: Thread in CPUs and threads in programs are two different things. Don't confuse them. And secondly Python is rarely using more than one CPU at a time when using multi-threading. This is a limitation dues to the [GIL](https://wiki.python.org/moin/GlobalInterpreterLock). What you need is [multiprocessing](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/multiprocessing.html).

Comment: This might be too broad for Stack Overflow. See [help/on-topic], [ask].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nominally, this is

```
import itertools
import multiprocessing as mp

def regress_me(vars):
    ind_var, dep_var = vars
    # your regression may be better than mine...
    result = "{} {}".format(ind_var, dep_var)
    return result

if __name__ == "__main__":
    with mp.Pool(8) as pool:
        analyse_this = list(itertools.product(independent_variables,
            dependent_variables))
        result = mp.map(regress_me, analyse_this)
```

A lot depends on what is being passed between parent and child and whether you are using a forking system like linux or a spawning system like windows. If these datasets are being fetched from disk, it may be better to do the read in the worker `regress_me` instead of passing it from the parent. You can read up on that with the standard python `multiprocessing` library.